# how can I compile fortran source with module file with fwrap?

Tags: fortran, cython, f2py

how can I compile fortran source with module file with fwrap?

I tested fwrapc --build ../test.f90 --fcompiler=gnu95
but I don't know how to compile test.f90 together with fmodule.f90.

```
/fmodule.f90 
module fmod
!implicit none
!integer, dimension(1,2), intent(inout) :: indata1
!integer*2, dimension(3), intent(inout) :: indata2
!integer, dimension(4,5), intent(inout) :: indata3
real*8, dimension(6) :: indata4
real, dimension(7,8) :: indata5
!Cf2py intent(in, out) indata4

end module fmod

/test.f90
      subroutine temp_f_2(indata4, indata5)
      use fmod
!real*8, dimension(6) :: indata4
!real, dimension(7,8) :: indata5

      !real*8, dimension(6) :: indata4
      !real, dimension(7,8) :: indata5

      do 10 i = 1, 6
      indata4(i) = 3
      10 continue 

!forall(i=1:2, j=1:2)
!indata5(i,j) = 5
!end forall
      print *, indata4
      end
```

Comment: I have no idea about the quality of answers you got on your previous questions, but if they are correct/ solved the problem, you should accept the answers. invites people to help you if they can assume to get their earned reward